# Is it possible to wrap this in a Python "with" statement?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it possible to use it to achieve the following? (using the "with" keyword or not)

Before:

```
try:
    raise Exception("hello")
except Exception as e:
    print "GOT IT"
```

Desired effect:

```
def safety():
    try:
        yield
    except Exception as e:
        print "GOT IT"

with safety():
    raise Exception("hello")
```

It just makes the code so much cleaner. Currently running the second snippet gives the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testing.py", line 25, in <module>
    with safety():
AttributeError: __exit__
```

Comment: what do you want to do? what is the expected behaviour? do you want to basically have giving a code example doesn't describe what you want to achieve.

Comment: I think he wants the resulting code behave like the first example. Can't think of a different interpretation TBH

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer: It might be hard to understand because it doesn't make sense to do that. You shouldn't attempt to replicate a try/except block with `with`.

Comment: using the with statement is one option the other one is to decorate the function. if you want this at function scope it might be cleaner: http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.org/en/latest/PythonDecorators.html on a side note: syntax error is also an exception that looks dangerous in python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You were so close!

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def safety():
    try:
        yield
    except Exception as e:
        print "GOT IT"

with safety():
    raise Exception("hello")
```

Comment: potentially precisely what the OP wants.

Comment: Oh snap, that was fast. Thank you sir.

Comment: Effectively the `contextmanager` adds the missing `.__exit__` attribute.